# Iterating JSON structure of list object and finding next keys

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a Json list and I want to print all the keys from a given key till the end of dictionary. But the code I wrote is very complex. How to do it with less complexity ?
I'm using **Python 3**

```
dictionary = [{"a": "1"}, {"b": "2"}, {"c": "3"}, {"d": "4"}]

try:
    for token in dictionary:
            if "b" in list(token.keys())[0]:
                new_dict = dictionary[len(list(token.keys())[0]):]
                for i in new_dict:
                    print(new_dict[len(list(i.keys())[0]):])
                break
            else:
                print("Inception")
except Exception as error:
    print(str(error))
```

**DESIRED** 
Input: **b** 
Output: **c, d**

**My Output**:

```
Inception
[{'c': '3'}, {'d': '4'}]
[{'c': '3'}, {'d': '4'}]
[{'c': '3'}, {'d': '4'}]
```

Comment: What's your desired output for the given data ? The question is unclear.

Comment: I mentioned the desired and the output I'm receiving.

Comment: Sounds like you want [`itertools.dropwhile()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile)..

Comment: `if 'b' in list(token.keys())[0]` should just be `if 'b' in token`. Dictionaries have no order, your test would be subject to the whim of insertion order and the current random hash seed if you have more than one key.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`itertools.dropwhile()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile) to skip all dictionaries that don't have a `'b'` key:

```
from itertools import dropwhile

filtered = dropwhile(lambda t: 'b' not in t, dictionary)
next(filtered)  # skip the dictionary with `b` in it.

for token in filtered:
    print(token)
```

This prints all dictionaries after the first. If you only need to print their keys, do so explicitly:

```
filtered = dropwhile(lambda t: 'b' not in t, dictionary)
next(filtered)  # skip the dictionary with `b` in it.

for token in filtered:
    print(*token, sep='\n')
```

This prints the keys on separate lines; if there is just one key, then that's all that'll be printed for each `token` dictionary.)

As a side note: you **really** do not want to use `list(dict.keys())[0]`. Before Python 3.6, dictionaries have no set order (instead [being subject to insertion and deletion history and the current random hash seed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479928/why-is-the-order-in-dictionaries-and-sets-arbitrary/)), so if you have more than one key what value you'll get is a gamble. And all you want to do is see if a key is present, so use a `key in dictobject` membership test.

To get the first key out of each dictionary, I'd use `next(iter(dictobject))`, avoiding creating a list:

```
first_key = next(iter(dictobject))
```

I'd only use this if I had *single-key* dictionaries. I'd also avoid using dictionaries for such a scenario; perhaps you really wanted to use an ordered dictionary instead (in Python < 3.6, use [`collections.OrderedDict()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict), otherwise use the [regular `dict` type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6)).

Comment: Thanks Martijin :) This helps.

Answer (score 2):

This is one way. The idea is to find the index of the dictionary with desired key. Then filter your list accordingly.

```
keys = [next(iter(x)) for x in dictionary]
res = keys[keys.index('b')+1:]
# ['c', 'd']
```

Comment: Thanks for the update jpp :)
But I just need c, d (i.e, only the keys). How can I find the keys?

Comment: Thanks jpp :) This helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can re-write your code as follows for your desired result.

```
found = False
for data in dictionary:
    if found:
        print(list(data.keys())[0])
    if 'b' in data.keys():
        found = True
```